# Auto weight paint is wack on other side of model, plus manual weight painting is jank

Tags: uv, weight-painting

Blender newbie here. I'm trying to create a dragon model, and all the automatic weight painting isn't helping. There are no doubles or anything, but weight paint only properly weighs one side and not the other. I've tried manually painting it, but for some reason or another, the manual weight painting doesn't work properly either, and the UV editing or whatever does not help no matter what I try. I have no idea what the problem is, and I will accept any answer that either fixes automatic weight painting, fixes manual weight painting, or provides an escape from this nightmare.

Sorry if what I've said doesn't describe my problem much, I am tired and angry and do not have much will or brainpower left to give. I'd provide screenshots, but I don't think those would help as much as they should, so here's a link to the model itself:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vaGENdYW1_V0ohBG2sF9Mmy4MTfrFbvO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should recalculate the normals of your mesh (Shift N), also apply the scale and rotation of your mesh and armature, and align the bones with the axis in Edit mode (Shift N), that said it won't help a lot when you'll parent With Automatic Weights, you'll need to weight paint to correct, probably because your object is a bit puffy so Blender struggles to find how to assign each vertex